# SHAP Error - OM when allocating tensor with shape[23020,128,768]

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, transformer-model, shap

I am trying to get shap values using  shap.KernelExplainer for a bert classifier implemented using keras layers. The error that I get comes because there is not enough memory. But I am not sure what it is causing it because I have reduced all the parameters to as much as I can.

**Error:**

> ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[23020,128,768] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:Tile]

**Transformer Model:**

```
def process_sentences(sentence: List[str],
                      tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer,
                      max_len: int) -> Dict[str, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Tokenize the text sentences.

    Parameters
    ----------
    sentence:
        Sentence to be processed.
    tokenizer:
        Tokenizer to be used.

    Returns
    -------
        Tokenized representation containing:
         - input_ids
         - attention_mask
    """
    # since we are using the model for classification, we need to include special char (i.e, '[CLS]', ''[SEP]')
    # check the example here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.4.2/quicktour.html
    z = tokenizer(sentence,
                  add_special_tokens=True,
                  padding='max_length',
                  max_length=max_len,
                  truncation=True,
                  return_attention_mask = True,
                  return_tensors='np')
    return z;


use_bert = True

if use_bert:
    from transformers import BertTokenizerFast
    tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
else:
    from transformers import DistilBertTokenizerFast
    tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')


if use_bert:
    from transformers import TFBertModel, BertConfig
    config = BertConfig(output_hidden_states=True)
    transformer = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=config)
else:
    from transformers import TFDistilBertModel, DistilBertConfig
    config = DistilBertConfig(output_hidden_states=True)
    transformer = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased', config=config)

X_train = train.clean_review.values.tolist()
X_test=test.clean_review.values.tolist()


# tokenize datasets
X_train = process_sentences(X_train, tokenizer, max_len)
X_test = process_sentences(X_test, tokenizer, max_len)

y_train = y_train.rate
y_test = y_test.rate


class Classifier(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 transformer,
                 hidden_dims: int = 128,
                 output_dims: int = 2,
                 dropout_rate: float = 0.2):
        """
        Constructor

        Parameters
        ----------
        transformer:
            Transformer model to be leveraged.
        hidden_dims:
            hidden layer's dimension.
        output_dims:
            Output layer's dimension.
        dropout_rate:
            Dropout layer's dropout rate.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_dims = hidden_dims
        self.output_dims = output_dims
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate

        self.transformer = transformer
        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.hidden_dims, activation='relu')
        self.dropout_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(self.dropout_rate)
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.output_dims, activation='softmax')

    def call(self,
             input_ids: Union[np.ndarray, tf.Tensor],
             attention_mask: Optional[Union[np.ndarray, tf.Tensor]]=None,
             training=False):
        """
        Performs forward pass throguh the model.

        Parameters
        ----------
        input_ids:
            Indices of input sequence tokens in the vocabulary.
        attention_mask:
            Mask to avoid performing attention on padding token indices.

        Returns
        -------
            Classification probabilities.
        """
        out = self.transformer(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, training=training)
        out = out.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]  # extract the embedding corresponding to [CLS] token
        out = self.dense_1(out)
        out = self.dropout_1(out, training=training)
        out = self.dense_2(out)
        return out
# define the classification model
model = Classifier(transformer)
```

**ShAP:**

```
##background

X_train=train.clean_review.values.tolist()[:10]
X_train = process_sentences(X_train, tokenizer, max_len)

# tokenize text
tokenized_samples = X_train
X_train = tokenized_samples['input_ids']

# the values of the kwargs have to be `tf.Tensor`.
# see transformers issue #14404: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14404
kwargs_train = {k:tf.constant(v) for k, v in tokenized_samples.items() if k == 'attention_mask'}

##SAMPLE
X_test=test.clean_review.values.tolist()[:3]
X_test = process_sentences(X_test, tokenizer, max_len)

# tokenize text
tokenized_samples = X_test
X_test = tokenized_samples['input_ids']

# the values of the kwargs have to be `tf.Tensor`.
# see transformers issue #14404: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14404
kwargs_test = {k:tf.constant(v) for k, v in tokenized_samples.items() if k == 'attention_mask'}
kernel_explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model, X_train)
kernel_shap_values = kernel_explainer.shap_values(X_test)
```

Comment: There is absolutely no chance you can place a 23020×128×768 float32 tensor on a GPU card. To learn why try to multiply axis dimensions by 32 and see the necessary GPU memory. You need to feed batches to your model.

Comment: You provided neither a [reprex] nor specified a line that throws an error. So, as a wild guess tinker with the last 2 lines of the code.